# windows form on program switch is still visible

Tags: c#

i have a form say "f" which is one of many forms in mdi but f is child of mdi.
suppose i open form f and when i switch program
(alt+tab) to other program ,the form "f" will be visible on other programs also .how to fix it

Form f ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [Form.TopMost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Form.TopLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.toplevel(v=vs.110).aspx) properties.